# editing datetime field backgrounds on focus on firefox

Tags: css, firefox

```
.input[type='time']::-moz-datetime-edit-hour-field:focus {
  background-color: #3783f6;
}
.input[type='time']::-moz-datetime-edit-minute-field:focus {
  background-color: #3783f6;
}
.input[type='time']::-moz-datetime-edit-ampm-field:focus {
  background-color: #3783f6;
}
```

I'm trying to change the background of my time fields when a user focuses or clicks on the specific fields. However, this isn't working and I was wondering if there was a specific selector for firefox instead?

I have tried just editing the input field's background color without focus and it works and it also changes color on chrome when I use

```
.input[type='time']::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field:focus {
  background-color: #3783f6;
}
.input[type='time']::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field:focus {
  background-color: #3783f6;
}
.input[type='time']::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field:focus {
  background-color: #3783f6;
}
```

And here is the Typescript:

```
 <Input
            type="time"
            name="pickupTime"
            className={styles.input}
            aria-labelledby="pickupLabel pickupTime"
            ref={register({
              required: true,
              validate: (pickupTime: string) => {
                const startDate = getValues('startDate');
                const pickup = moment(`${startDate} ${pickupTime}`);
                return startDate
                  ? isTimeValid(startDate, pickupTime) &&
                      checkBounds(startDate, pickup)
                  : true;
              },
            })}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time make sure to include more of your code as debugging without it is a coin toss.

At a first glance, you put a "." in front of input which prompts a search for a class named "input" and I doubt it'll find any.

When trying to select an input element of a certain type make sure you select the tag itself, in your case being "input[type='time']::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field:focus { css rules here }"